# Problem with Microsoft.CodeAnalysis on Visual Studio 2019 16.11.6 AFTER install Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#

I am receiving on Visual Studio 2019 16.11.6 these suspicious warnings (Version=42.42.42.42) AFTER install Visual Studio 2022.
Any idea?

Warning CS8032 An instance of analyzer System.Text.Json.SourceGeneration.JsonSourceGenerator cannot be created from C:\Users\xyz.nuget\packages\system.text.json\6.0.0\analyzers\dotnet\roslyn4.0\cs\System.Text.Json.SourceGeneration.dll: Der Typ "Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.IIncrementalGenerator" in der Assembly "Microsoft.CodeAnalysis, **Version=42.42.42.42**, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" konnte nicht geladen werden.

Answer (score 0):

[From GitHub issues:](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/61602)

> **Actual behavior**
>
> The build produces the following warning (or error if TreatWarningsAsErrors is enabled)
>
> **Known Workarounds**
>
> You can pass DisableSystemTextJsonSourceGenerator to disable all versions of the generator: dotnet build -p:DisableSystemTextJsonSourceGenerator=true.

Based on [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/244179/microsoftcodeanalysis-problem.html) -
I solved this issue on my machine by updating Visual Studio 2019 to the latest version (16.11.13).